# Windows IDE for Intel x86 Assembler?

Tags: assembly, ide, x86, intel

Are there any IDEs (similar to Visual Studio) in which one can code and run Intel assembly? I believe I came across an Intel suite previously, but the product was quite expensive.

At university we used a development IDE/Simulator for ARM, but was hoping for one for Intel x86.

Comment: Is this for Linux, Windows, or something else? Are you using MASM? NASM? Google will be your friend here.

Comment: I did try googling in the past but i couldnt believe there was a nice ARM development suite but nothing for intel which was free.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[MASM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Macro_Assembler) is an x86 assembler for Windows that uses the Intel syntax. ([MASM Homepage](http://www.masm32.com/))

For an IDE, you could use MASM with Visual Studio, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/masm-for-x64-ml64-exe?view=msvc-160), or you could use something smaller like [RadASM](https://github.com/mrfearless/RadASM2). [WinASM](https://www.winasm.org/) is also another one.

When I do any ASM on my Linux box I use NASM plus a text editor (gedit).

Answer (score 2):

Why not [Visual Studio](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/vsasm.html)?

Comment: Can you output to the 'console' like you can in C# etc?

Comment: Because all those instructions are a pain in the arse and refer to an older version of VS. I wanna be stuck on assembly problems, not configuring VS to use assembly..... 

There must be something which is <write assembly> <choose assembly compiler> <run assembly> ??

Comment: @user997112: WinASM as said in the other answer lets you choose your assembler, linker, resource compiler...etc. I have used it for years.

Answer (score 2):

[SASM](http://dman95.github.io/SASM/english.html) is a open source cross platform ASM IDE.